# SAS: Reading all files containing a specific string

Tags: sas

I would like to read a set of files that all contain a specific string (xxx*.csv). So if my folder has the files below, the code should read in file #1 and #2.
1. xxx_123.csv
2. xxx_456.csv
3. xyz_111.csv

The first part of the filename is known, but the second part is unknown. Anyone know how I can achieve this in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a wildcard fileref, not sure how to do it interactively in EG, but in Base SAS the code would be similar to the below.

```
filename wildxxx "/path/xxx*.csv" ;

data readin ;
  infile wildxxx /* + infile options */;
  /* input statement */
run ;
```